# Attribute selector where value equals either A or B?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I was wondering if it is possible to specify elements in CSS where an attribute is equal to one of two values, something like this:

```
input[type=text][type=password]
```

However this selector does not seem to work (I assume because specifying the same attribute twice is not valid), does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Specifying the same attribute twice is valid. Specifying the same attribute twice with different values is also valid. It's just that the latter is contradictory and impossible to fulfill.

Comment: Yeah I misunderstood the way it handled multiple attribute selectors, thought it might be an or case, but it was working as an and case.

Comment: More general question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517429/css-selector-a-or-b-and-c , not only attribute, and nested matters.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You may simply list them as individual selectors:

```css
input[type="username"],
input[type="password"] {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Username: <input type="username" name="Username" value="Username" />

  Password: <input type="password" name="Password" value="Password" />

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: This answer is actually invalid, your solution requires two separate selectors. Just as @boltclock mentioned, there is no singular selector that can match multiple values of an attribute.

Comment: @biphobe OP did not specify they wanted *one* selector. They wanted to know how to do OR logic with attributes, and this is how. Your comment is invalid.

Comment: I agree that it's good that this answer is supplied here, even though it kind-of not explicitly answers the question - it's like saying to askers: "this is the way..."

Answer (score 13):

One option nowadays is `:is`, a little cleaner and saves characters as the list of selectors increases:

```
<style>
  input:is([type=text], [type=password]) { background-color: red }
</style>

<input type="text"> red
<input type="password"> red
<input type="email"> white
```

MDN has some useful examples that show where a major reduction in the number of selectors can be had using `:is` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is

Comment: Great one yet browser support is here and there, use only if you are comfortable with the risks. See this link for information on browser support `:is:` https://caniuse.com/?search=is()

Comment: It has 100% support from all the latest browsers and CSS tools can add support for older browsers using the old syntax.