# WebDriverWait for multiple conditions (OR logical evaluation)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

Using python, the method WebDriverWait is used to wait for 1 element to be present on the webpage. 
How can this method be used without multiple try/except?
Is there an OR option for multiple cases using this method?
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: you can use OR in XPATH locators.  The ExpectedCondition always returns a single bool.  What is the use-case?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Without using multiple `try/except{}` to induce *WebDriverWait* for two elements through OR option you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".element_A_class, .element_B_class"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH` through [lambda](/questions/tagged/lambda):

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"element_A_xpath") or driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"element_B_xpath"))
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [selenium two xpath tests in one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57890400/selenium-two-xpath-tests-in-one/57891188#57891188)
- [Python / Selenium: Logic Operators in WebDriverWait Expected Conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46147145/python-selenium-logic-operators-in-webdriverwait-expected-conditions/46147830#46147830)

Comment: The multi-match `By.xpath` worked for me. It is a little odd, but it works. P.S. This is Selenium-general, not Python-specific.

Comment: The second one is not working for my case. Have to use `waiter.until(EC.any_of(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "a")), EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "b"))))`

Answer (score 0):

also you can use EC methods, but you have to consider a rule:
→ always pass your driver object to EC method like below:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(lambda driver: {your custom condition one} [or, and] EC.alert_is_present()(driver) [or, and] ...)
```

---

high-light from top section **you have to pass driver like bottom**

```
lambda driver: EC.alert_is_present()(driver)
```

---

in this example the driver wait for 100 seconds or window.alert is present [or, and] (condition one is True)