# Any built-in way for branching waits with OR conditions?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

After I click a button on a webpage, one of two things can happen.  Normally, I would use a wait until when there's a single event outcome, but is there any built in methodology where I can wait until 1 of two things happens i.e. one of two elements exists?

Comment: Xpath | or statements would be what your looking for. Driver.find_element_by_xpath(" x | y ")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To wait until either of two elements you can induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for either of the two elements through the *`OR`* option and you can use either of the following approaches:

- Using *CssSelector* you can pass the expressions seperated by comma as follows:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".classA, .classB"))
  ```
- Using *CssSelector* and [lambda](/questions/tagged/lambda) you can pass the expressions through `OR` condition as follows:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tagname.classname") or driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tagname#elementID"))
  ```
- Using *XPath* you can pass the expressions through `OR` condition as follows:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//tag_name[@class='elementA' or @id='elementB']"))
  ```
- Using *XPath* and [lambda](/questions/tagged/lambda) you can pass the expressions through `OR` condition as follows:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"xpathA") or driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"xpathB"))
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [WebDriverWait for multiple conditions (OR logical evaluation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60496204/webdriverwait-for-multiple-conditions-or-logical-evaluation/60496760#60496760)
- [selenium two xpath tests in one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57890400/selenium-two-xpath-tests-in-one/57891188#57891188)
- [Python / Selenium: Logic Operators in WebDriverWait Expected Conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46147145/python-selenium-logic-operators-in-webdriverwait-expected-conditions/46147830#46147830)

Comment: Just adding a point. If both elements are having same tag then `xPath` can be written like this `//div[@id='PEGA_GRID_CONTENT' or @gpropindex='PNewDetails1']` as well

Comment: Updated the answer with the above mentioned clause

Answer (score 0):

you can do it tbh this is in java i dont know about python but this is at least an idea if you have two condition to be met for example input 1 to be present and input 2
I would create two boolean variabels that i will put in them `driver.findelements(by....).size()>0;`
then i will just add an if so in case not both of them show it will crash or do what ever i want.
Code example:

```
    Boolean AccesViaLogin = driver.findElements(By.id("username_login")).size() > 0;
    Boolean AccesViaHomepage = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),\"Connexion\")]")).size() > 0;
    if (AccesViaLogin == true && AccesViaHomepage == true) {
}
```