# We have @FindBys and @FindAll in Selenium Java, how to use same code to find locators in Python

Tags: python, selenium, findall, findby, findelement

We have @FindBys and @FindAll in Selenium Java, how to use same code to find locators in Python?

```
@FindBys( { @FindBy(className = "class1") @FindBy(className = "class2")} )
```

Please guide me someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple ways:

- Using *lambda* and *CLASS_NAME*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "class1") or driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "class2"))
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".class1, .class2"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Any built-in way for branching waits with OR conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70041097/any-built-in-way-for-branching-waits-with-or-conditions/70103427#70103427)
- [WebDriverWait for multiple conditions (OR logical evaluation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60496204/webdriverwait-for-multiple-conditions-or-logical-evaluation/60496760#60496760)

Comment: Thank you second one worked for me using CSSSelector.