# CSS multiple execution of a rule

Tags: html, css

in the following example i want to visualize two states of an element with the same style. The element should look the same regardless of wheter it is in state "foo" or "bar". It is also possible that the element has both states

```
<div id="elem" foo bar></div>
```

CSS Style

```
#elem {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

#elem[foo],
#elem[bar] {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

In this example the rule is selected twice for the same element, if the foo and bar attributes are set. Is there a better way, or is it perhaps a performance or visualization problem?

thank you

Comment: This is no performance problem whatsoever. Also, the rule is not selected twice.

Comment: This question seems to be similar https://stackoverflow.com/q/7517429/5859685 have you seen it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS is told to be slow. It applies to a phenomenon called reflow/repaint. And it to a minor extent applies to selector efficiency. Many selectors with identical style properties being applied consecutively is a specific practical case. Let's dig into it.

For example, you have an element:

```
<p class="first">Lorem ipsum</p>
```

and then you add another class so it becomes

```
<p class="first second">Lorem ipsum</p>
```

Now, let's say, the "lead" and "first" classes have identical properties:

```
.first,
.second {
  color: green;
}
```

When the "second" class gets applied to that particular "p" element, the browser will surely apply new CSS rules and then calculate the difference; because there's no difference, the browser won't repaint. If you use Chrome DevTools (Performance tab) to track what actually happens, there will literally be 0 frames per second painted, although there will be an operation "Recalculate Style" taking a few microseconds.

Let's say we remove a class and bring it back to

```
<p class="first">Lorem ipsum</p>
```

Still no repaint.

But now, let's introduce another class with different properties:

```
.third {
  color: blue;
}
```

and add this class to our "p":

```
<p class="first second third">Lorem ipsum</p>
```

In this case, the "color" style property of "p" will change, which will cause repaint. On an iPhone 7 (Safari) it took 4.8ms total at 208fps rate to perform this operation. The latency is pretty low, however, depending on the set of styles being changed, performance may vary.

So, yes, one more rule in CSS that would apply identical style properties leads to one more check that actually takes time, but this time is negligible. I'm pretty sure you have more important things to optimize.

---

For further reading, there's a nice tutorial on rendering performance worth reading, [Reduce the Scope and Complexity of Style Calculations](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/reduce-the-scope-and-complexity-of-style-calculations).

Finally, there's [a very nice compilation of all the things that cause reflow/repaint](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a) worth reading as well.