# Opposite selector of :not(.classA, .classB, .classC) for a (X and (A or B or C)) selector

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

Given a dynamically generated class list:

```
let dynamicClassList = ".classA, .classB, .classC"; // Contains 0 to N classes
```

Using the `:not()` selector, I can easily build the negative selector `classX && !(classA || classB || classC)` like such:

```
$(".classX:not(" + dynamicClassList + ")");
```

But I can't figure out how to build the positive selector `classX && (classA || classB || classC)` as the [`matches()` selector doesn't seem compatible with browsers yet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26865964/1046013):

```
$(".classX:matches(" + dynamicClassList + ")");
```

Anybody knows a way of building that quick selector in a similar way of using `not()` without needing "loops" and "ifs"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the selector `classX && (classA || classB || classC)` to `(classX && classA) || (classX && classB) || (classX && classC)`

Which is the following CSS selector:

```
.classX.classA, .classX.classB, .classX.classC {}
```

Then you can consider a small JS code to add the `.classX` in order to create the selector:

```js
let dynamicClassList = ".classA, .classB, .classC";

let selector = dynamicClassList.replace(/,/gi, '.classX, ');
selector=selector+'.classX';

$(selector).css('color','red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="classA classX">some text</div>
<div class="classB">some text</div>
<div class="classX classB">some text</div>
<div class="classX classB classA">some text</div>
<div class="classB classA">some text</div>
<div class="classX">some text</div>
```

Comment: I guess there's no other way using a quick CSS selector huh? I feared the solution was to make some manipulations like this.. Well that works anyways, thanks friend!

Comment: @NaturalBornCamper: That's precisely why they introduced :matches() to begin with - there is no existing syntax sugar for this. If there were, there wouldn't need to be a :matches().