# Is there a shorter way in CSS to do this?

Tags: html, css

I have tons of CSS code I may have a better way to write.

For example, I want to make `H1` tags red on very specific places on the HTML page.

```css
.format-seven.blue #page-content h1,
.format-seven.green #page-content h1{
  color: red;
}
```

I could have used:

```css
h1{
color: red;
}
```

But, I really need the specificity of all the `".format-seven.blue #page-content"` part and the `".format-seven.green #page-content"` in this case.

Note the "green" and "blue" part.

It would be nice if I could do something like:

```css
.format-seven.[green|blue] #page-content h1{
  color: red;
}
```

Is there such a thing?

Comment: [this may can answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517429/css-selector-a-or-b-and-c)

Comment: try with this working fine on chrome & Firefox `div:-moz-any(.green, .blue) #page-content h1`  https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/p1bzdg6q/49/

Answer (score 2):

No unfortunately there is not in vanilla CSS. If you are concerned about how much you need to write, the big CSS Preprocessors have tools for scripting the generation of your stylesheets

[Here is a link to a great CSS Preprocessor (SASS)](https://sass-lang.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just create classes for your colors and then add them straight to the tags you want to change color for, like so:

```
.redText {color: red;}
.blueText {color: blue;}
```

and your markup:

```
<div class="format-seven blue">
   <div id="page-content">
      <h1 class="redText">Your Header</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a CSS preprocessor (Sass, Less, ...) as @nathan-fries told.

Then you can do something like that:

```
.format-seven {
  &.blue, &.green {
    #page-content h1 {
      color: red;
    }
    #something-else {
      background: red;
    }
  }
  &.yellow, &.black {
    #page-content h1 {
      color: yellow;
    }
  }
}
```

It will be compiled to:

```css
.format-seven.blue #page-content h1,
.format-seven.green #page-content h1 {
  color: red;
}
.format-seven.blue #something-else,
.format-seven.green #something-else {
  background: red;
}
.format-seven.yellow #page-content h1,
.format-seven.black #page-content h1 {
  color: yellow;
}
```

If you're coding with Visual Studio Code, I suggest using [Less Compiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.LESSCompiler) extension to compile less files on save.