# How do I specify a css selector which matches exactly one of multiple values?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have multiple input elements in a form. I would like to specify a single css selector for all input elements that have an attribute "type" with value either "text" or "email". How do I specify a single selector?

e.g.

```
#ABC.XYZ .MNQ input[type="text"] {
margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

I know I can put a comma at the end and repeat the whole selector with the type="email". Wondering if there is a shorter form to do the same with any special operators?

Comment: There's no shorter way I know of. Just write the css code and move on. :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attribute selector where value equals either A or B?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313711/attribute-selector-where-value-equals-either-a-or-b)

Comment: If you want less typing for you, use a CSS preprocessor (Sass, LESS, etc.).  Whether you type it out by hand or let the preprocessor do it, the selector will have to be `#ABC.XYZ .MNQ input[type="text"] , #ABC.XYZ .MNQ input[type="email"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure the quickest way is:

```
#ABC.XYZ .MNQ input[type="text"] , #ABC.XYZ .MNQ input[type="email"] {
margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

It would look nice to have a shorter selection line; but for overall code execution efficiency there would be no difference.